# Smooth scale animation JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a page that has a pointer down image,and when user enter's a cursor on it the list of products must be displayed and pointer will be compressed. And everything works fine except animation. I'm using JQuery methods:

```
    $(".product_picker").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).parent(".catalog_element").css({"border": "2px solid #676f7c","border-radius": "3px"});
        $(this).find(".fb_content").css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).find(".pointer_down").css({"transition": "all 0.5s","cursor": "pointer","height": "1px"});
    });
    $(".catalog_element").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css("border", "0px solid #676f7c");
        $(this).find(".fb_content").css({"transition":"all 0.5s","display": "none"});
        $(this).find(".pointer_down").css({"transition": "all 0.5s","cursor": "pointer","height": "auto"});
    });
```

product_picker is a div with pointer down, and I'm trying to scale it using css method but it scales without animation.I thought "transition": "all 0.5s" would do the trick, but it didn't. What I'm missing or how to make it smooth?.

Comment: If you add some html to the question and turn it into a runnable snippet, it might be way easier to answer.

Comment: Why not put the css stuff in css and just add/remove class with jquery. You only need to add a class to the parent the rest can be css

Comment: @Huangism Your solution worked. Thanks

Comment: @Danil.B you can post your code as your answer but provide complete/simplified code so future readers can take advantage of it, if you don't want to post an answer then you might as well remove the question because the question has incomplete code and has no answer so far, it won't be that useful for future readers. I would love to see the solution because it will be more helpful

Comment: @Huangism Done.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution(thanks to Huangism). The solution is to add new css class to pointer down(which is going to be shrunk). So, I've changed JQuery script to this:

```
$(".product_picker").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).parent(".catalog_element").css({"border": "2px solid #676f7c","border-radius": "3px"});
    $(this).find(".fb_content").css({"display": "block"});
    $(this).find(".pointer_down").addClass("shrunk_pointer_down");
});
$(".catalog_element").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css("border", "0px solid #676f7c");
    $(this).find(".fb_content").css({"transition":"all 0.5s","display": "none"});
    $(this).find(".pointer_down").removeClass("shrunk_pointer_down");
});
```

And I've changed css like this:

```
.shrunk_pointer_down{
    height: 1px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.pointer_down{
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: So do not use `.attr` to add/remove class, it is expensive, use `addClass` and `removeClass` https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ and https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ You can also use the same technique for the other elements too, if they are contained in the same parent, you can get away with adding 1 class to the parent and use css to take care of all of them instead of adding multiple classes